# Wait for All Fades in a Function to Finish Before the Next Function Starts

Tags: jquery

I've looked and seen some responses to this type of problem, but still can't wrap my mind around it.  I have a function with 5 different animations finishing at different times.  I want this function to completely finish it's inner functions' animations before the next function starts.

HTML

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>
<div id="div6"></div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
  background-color:red;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
#div2 {
  background-color:blue;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
#div3 {
  background-color:green;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
#div4 {
  background-color:yellow;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
#div5 {
  background-color:orange;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
#div6 {
  background-color:black;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  display:none;
}
```

JQuery / JS

```
fadeAll(); // I want to wait for all of the fadeOuts in this function to complete before...
$('#div6').fadeIn(); // .. this function starts.

function fadeAll() {
  $('#div1').fadeOut('slow');
  $('#div2').fadeOut('fast');
  $('#div3').fadeOut();
  $('#div4').fadeOut('fast');
  $('#div5').fadeOut();  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery's documentation about [fadeout](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/). There you will see that it can have a `complete` property. Let's see whether this example helps you:

```
var fades = 0;

function fadeOut(context, duration, callback) {
    fades++;
    context.fadeOut(duration, function() {
        fades--;
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    });
}

function fadeAll(callback) {
  fadeOut($("#div1"), 'slow', callback);
  fadeOut($("#div2"), 'fast', callback);
  fadeOut($("#div3"), undefined, callback);
  fadeOut($("#div4"), 'fast', callback);
  fadeOut($("#div5"), undefined, callback);  
}

function fadeCallback() {
    if (fades === 0) {
        $('#div6').fadeIn();
    }
}

fadeAll(fadeCallback);
```

Here we have a counter to know how many fadeouts are we waiting for. We increase this number when a `fadeOut` is called and decrease it when such an event is completed. We decrease it before calling the callback and the callback checks that value. If it is 0, then callback is called.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm starting to get how callbacks work finally.  But I don't understand this line `callback && callback();` What exactly does that do?

[Here's the fiddle again](https://jsfiddle.net/kevmon/g06v8e4o/1/)

Comment: && is true if and only if both operands are truey. The second operand will be evaluated if and only if the first was truey. If callback is truey, then callback() will be evaluated (called). If callback is falsy, then the second operand will not be evaluated. So, if you pass a callback function, then it will be truey, therefore called. If you do not pass a callback, then it will be undefined, therefore not called. As a result, the line can be translated to "if there is a callback, execute it". If my answer solved your problem, then please mark it as a correct answer.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  So the logic all makes sense, it's just not working.  I'm getting a console error, "callback is not defined"

Comment: @Kevmon, the code was not tested. I have made an edit to my answer. Is it working now?

Comment: Not quite yet, but the other error is gone.  Now there's this one  --> `VM2944:79Uncaught TypeError: context.fadeOut is not a function`.  I'm trying as well, but not knowledgeable enough yet to see what's wrong.

Comment: Nevermind, `context.fadeOut`needed to be changed to `$(context).fadeOut`.  Thank you!